# How to add tiny break in border for html input

Tags: html, css, input, border

Is it possible to add break for borders? I did not find correct solution. maybe i should do it with pseudo element and background? I can`t insert image in the question yet, so i attached link to image
[break in border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCUDh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this way

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.border{
  border:2px solid pink;
  border-radius:5px;
  height:34px;
  position:relative;
}
.border input{
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  border:0;
  padding:5px 8px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.border:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:6px;
  height:2px;
  background:#fff;
  left:50%;
  top:-2px;
  margin-left:-3px;
}
.border:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:6px;
  height:2px;
  background:#fff;
  left:50%;
  bottom:-2px;
  margin-left:-3px;
}

<div class="border">
    <input class="" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/vodzhxc0/

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I understand the main idea